# Lightweight HTTP router

Tags: wcf, http, routes, router

Is there some lightweight HTTP router? It is needed to do the following: there are several client applications that are going to connect to a server using the same port because of firewall: only several ports are usually opened and there is no possibility to open it.

Client applications use WCF (over HTTP) or just HTTP for communication with a server. It is possible to distinguish them by HTTP headers (URLs are different for different applications). So the thing needed is to parse HTTP requests and then redirect them to appropriate port depending on URL. I don't want to use IIS or some other web server for this task because it is too heavy. I want some lightweight solution- some application or simple framework where I can create rules for forwarding and that's it, nothing more is needed.

I've found some HTTP parsers, for example https://github.com/bvanderveen/httpmachine, but I have manually redirect requests, probably there are some tools which can do all the job for me. I think this kind of task is popular and there should be some lightweight solutions. Could you recommend any?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx

Comment: @Valamas-AUS That's HTTP simulator to simulate requests, not a HTTP router. I need to redirect requests to another port depending on HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who interested - I've found a great tool called FiddlerCore [link](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) which perfectly satisfies my requirements.